# Can't get rid of ubuntu 22.04 notification: "Software Updates Installed"

Tags: 22.04, update-manager, notification

Every time my computer boots up, I get this notification:
[Software updates installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf9nE.png)

My update cycle is set to every two weeks and I can't figure out how to tell the system, that I've noticed this particular notification.

I do not want to disable the notifications all together.

The whole system is up-to-date. I've opened the notification, I've clicked through all the update information, and I've rebooted a few times to no avail.

Comment: I have the same question and still do not know the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that both gnome-software (apt package) and snap-store (snap) were installed... Removing the one I don't use (in my case gnome-software) solved the issue.

Hope it helps...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I followed your advice and uninstalled flatpack and snap support in the GNOME Software.
In UBUNTU Software I cant change that setting though. It appears that both apps have the same function and I therefore do not understand the reason of having two apps do the same.

Anyway, it appears that I have solved the issue of the persistent "software updates installed" notification, I hope I have not created another problem though.